# How to correct the time data from 'csv' file and plot the graph in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I want to use the time data to plot the pictures,  I want use the time as `x-label`. But the time data in the CSV file (automatically generated by Datalogger) includes `mS`. I want to read the time data and one or two columns data as `y`.
But the plots cannot be drawn. Since I am a beginner in Python, I hope If someone can help me to solve this problem, Thanks a lot.

the CSV data looks like:

```
2016/04/27 13:48:00.042,n,-2.544222,5.593792,14.599032,20.487942,27.729218    
2016/04/27 13:49:00.000,n,-2.430035,5.625136,14.800756,20.447172,27.704616
```

my code:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from collections import namedtuple
import os, sys, glob, math
import random
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

figname="wang_redox_potential.png"
fig=figure(figsize=(16, 16), dpi=100)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='auto')
rc("font", size=20)
rc('pdf',fonttype =42)
xlabel("$t\ [min]$")
ylabel("$Eh\ [mv]$")
ylim(-400,400)
colors=['r','b','g','m','k','brown']
labels=['redox1','redox2','redox3','redox4','redox5','redox6']
data = pd.read_csv("wang.csv")
j=0
with open('./wang.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)    
    for row in f_csv:
         time=row[0]
         dateraw=time[:-4]
         date = datetime.datetime.strptime (dateraw,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
         for i in range(1,7): 
                 plot_date(date,data[:,16+i],ls='-',color=colors[i- 1],lw=2,label=labels[i-1])             
         j+=1

legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),fontsize=20)
savefig(figname,bbox_inches='tight')
close()

print('success')
```

Comment: What do you mean "the plots cannot be drawn", do you have an error ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem is the correct time data can not be get. Because I have successfully used the sequence number like 1,2,3 to draw the plots.